# Blank page when trying to open file from jupiter menu in browser

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I ran Jupyter notebook from Windows 10 cmd, and I get web page in browser on localhost. Now, when trying to open one file (.ipynb, size 1KB) from menu,
I get blank browser, It looks like page is loading, but It never happens. What can be problem ?

[image]